# Solving for the equation, giving exact solutions between (0 and $2\pi$)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the problem: $\sin(2x)=\tan(x)$

I used the double angle formula to get $2\sin(x)\cos(x)=\tan(x)$.

But after that step, I do not know whether or not to subtract $\tan(x)$ or to set $2\sin(x)\cos(x)$ to $u$ and solve for $U$.

Answer (score 3):

$$
2\sin(x)\cos(x)=\tan(x)
$$

Here, two possibilities: $\sin(x) = 0 \implies x \in \{ 0, \pi, 2\pi\}$

or
$$
2\cos(x)=\frac 1{\cos x}
\iff \cos^2 x = \frac 12
\iff x \in \left\{ \frac \pi 4, \frac {3\pi} 4, \frac {5\pi} 4, \frac {7\pi} 4
\right\} 
$$

Answer (score 3):

Write $\tan{(x)}=\frac{\sin (x)}{\cos(x)}$
allowing you to write it as:
$$ 2\sin{(x)}\cos{(x)}=\frac{\sin{(x)}}{\cos(x)} $$

After a little manipulation you can get it into this form:
$$ \sin{(x)}(2\cos^2(x)-1) =0$$
So you are then solving:
$$ \sin(x)=0 \;\;\; \text{ and } \;\;\; 2\cos^2(x)-1=0 $$
Can you see how to proceed from here?

Comment: How did you manipulate the cosines to get cosine squared?

Comment: @Erin $2\sin(x)\cos(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$ then we multiply both sides by $\cos(x)$ to get: $2\sin(x)\cos^2(x)=\sin(x) $ then subtract $\sin(x)$ from both sides: $2\sin(x)\cos^2(x)-\sin(x)=0 $ then factor out the $\sin(x)$: $\sin(x)(2\cos^2(x)-1)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$2\sin x\cos x=\dfrac{\sin x}{\cos x}\\
\implies \cos x=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\text{ and/or }\sin x=0\\
\implies x=\dfrac{\pi}{4},\dfrac{3\pi}{4},\dfrac{5\pi}{4},\dfrac{7\pi}{4},0,\pi,2\pi$$